# Can we scan multiple PDS files for certain text and count all found matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I'm trying to hack together some code to scan through multiple PDF files, which are all resumes, find words that match some search terms, and count all the matches.  So, if one resume has 'Python' listed 5x, I want to capture that and if it has 'Excel' listed 4x, I want to capture that.  I want everything listed in a dataframe.  Here is the code that I am working with.  I think it is close, but something is definitely not right here.

```
import PyPDF2
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

#Function to read resumes from the folder one by one
mypath='C:\\Users\\Resume Parser\\' #enter your path here where you saved the resumes
onlyfiles = [os.path.join(mypath, f) for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath, f))]

def pdfextract(file):
    fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
    countpage = fileReader.getNumPages()
    count = 0
    text = []
    while count < countpage:    
        pageObj = fileReader.getPage(count)
        count +=1
        t = pageObj.extractText()
        print (t)
        text.append(t)
    return text

#function to read resume ends
keywords = ['Microsoft Word','Excel','PowerPoint','Python','NLP']
    
#function that does phrase matching and builds a candidate profile
def create_profile(file):
    text = pdfextract(file) 
    text = str(text)
    text = text.replace("\\n", "")
    text = text.lower()
    #below is the csv where we have all the keywords, you can customize your own
    
    print(keywords)
    WORD_words = [nlp(text) for text in keywords['Microsoft Word'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    XL_words = [nlp(text) for text in keywords['Excel'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    PP_words = [nlp(text) for text in keywords['PowerPoint'].dropna(axis = 0)]
    NLP_words = [nlp(text) for text in keywords['NLP'].dropna(axis = 0)]


    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    matcher.add('Stats', None, *WORD_words)
    matcher.add('NLP', None, *XL_words)
    matcher.add('ML', None, *PP_words)
    matcher.add('DL', None, *NLP_words)
    doc = found(text)
    
    d = []  
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        d.append((rule_id, span.text))      
    keywords = "\n".join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} ({j})' for i,j in Counter(d).items())
    
    ## convertimg string of keywords to dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(keywords),names = ['Keywords_List'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Keywords_List.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['Subject','Keyword'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.Keyword.str.split('(',1).tolist(),columns = ['Keyword', 'Count'])
    df3 = pd.concat([df1['Subject'],df2['Keyword'], df2['Count']], axis =1) 
    df3['Count'] = df3['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip(")"))
    
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
       
    name = filename.split('_')
    name2 = name[0]
    name2 = name2.lower()
    ## converting str to dataframe
    name3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(name2),names = ['Candidate Name'])
    
    dataf = pd.concat([name3['Candidate Name'], df3['Subject'], df3['Keyword'], df3['Count']], axis = 1)
    dataf['Candidate Name'].fillna(dataf['Candidate Name'].iloc[0], inplace = True)

    return(dataf)
        
#function ends
        
#code to execute/call the above functions

final_database=pd.DataFrame()
i = 0 
while i < len(onlyfiles):
    file = onlyfiles[i]
    dat = create_profile(file)
    final_database = final_database.append(dat)
    i +=1
    print(final_database)
```

Or...is it just too hard to scan PDF files?  I know text files can csv files are very clean.  Maybe PDF files can be very difficult to work with.  Anyway, if this is doable, I would love to see a working solution.

Comment: did you get text from `pdfextract` function using `PyPDF2`?

Comment: The function is named 'create_profile'.  I had a slightly more complex version of the code that I posted, but it didn't really work.  It didn't find text that I know for a fact was in the PDFs.  I tried to streamline the code and now it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `PyMuPDF` for my current project, which is very similar as to extract information from bank statements in PDF format. Not sure if this library fits your needs but it's an option if `PyPDF2` doesn't work. I find it's very handy.

**code snippet**

```
import fitz # this enables to use PyMuPDF 
pdf_file = 'path/to/resumes/'
doc = fitz.open(pdf_file)
page = doc.loadPage(0) # only loads the first page of each doc assuming each resume is 1 page
pageTextblocks = page.getText('blocks') # This creates a list of items (x0,y0,x1,y1,"line1\nline2\nline3...",...)
pageTextblocks.sort(key=lambda block: block[3])
for block in pageTextblocks:
    targetBlock = block[4] # This gets to the content of doc 
    # do things here
```

if resume has multiple pages, you could do:

```
noOfPages = doc.pageCount
for pageNo in range(noOfPages):
    page = doc.loadPage(pageNo)
    # do things here
```

Just some ideas on extracting PDFs and [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the official doc if you need more info.